# Chrome extension's call to getHardwarePlatformInfo returning an error of "Not allowed"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, chromium

I am trying to use Google's enterprise.hardwarePlatform API to get the make and model of the Chromebook my extension is installed on using a call to: `chrome.enterprise.hardwarePlatform.getHardwarePlatformInfo`

However, when my callback is called, the object that should contain the information is null. Using `chrome.runtime.lastError` I get an error that just says "Not allowed".

I have doubled checked that:

- The Chromebook I have installed the extension on is using a Chrome version that should support the API.
- The extension is pushed out via an enterprise policy.
- The enterprise.hardwarePlatform permission is requested in the extension's manifest.

I have been searching for a solution for some time and the only clue I have found is this source code, but I still can not find a way to fix the issue: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/72.0.3626.80/chrome/browser/extensions/api/enterprise_hardware_platform/enterprise_hardware_platform_api.cc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You also need to [enable this API via policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#EnterpriseHardwarePlatformAPIEnabled).

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I am trying to enable the API for use on ChromeOS devices but I can't seem to find the option anywhere in the Google Developer Console, or within GSuite. Could you please point me in the right direction for how to enable the API?

Comment: I don't know myself. I would use google search to find an instruction.